# Lambda function error

Tags: python, lambda

I am creating Lambda function in Python.But I am running in some issue.
Here is the code of function:-

```
import boto3

import wfm

import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return "OK"
```

I am getting following error:-

```
"module initialization error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith' "
```

Any help here would be helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you running your code on Amazon? If not you might want to change the "aws-lambda" tag.

Comment: yes on Amazon so added the tag

Answer (score 0):

No errors I this code. I think the error is in your importing module.

Comment: I installed following modules:- pip install boto3,  pip instal wfm

Answer (score 0):

As mention above most probably you're missing some packages.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

You don't need to install `boto3`, because is already available inside lambda.

Answer (score 0):

An `error` of the type:

```
module initialization error
```

says it in the name that the problem is coming from when you initialise the `modules` that you are `importing` at the top of your `script`.

It is pretty much impossible that the `os` module will be giving you grief, but it is likely that either the `boto3` of `wfm` module is throwing the `error`. Unfortunately, I can't help with anything specific due to the nature of the problem, but I would suggest `updating` the `modules` to the *latest* versions.

Hopefully the people who make the `modules` will have fixed this `bug`.